# Push to array if the variable has been set

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think this is a relatively simple thing I'm trying to do, but unsure how to accomplish it. Essentially I have an array to which I want to push a value (parent) ONLY if that value exists. I'm trying to accomplish it like so, but this doesn't compile. I want to only set the parent index if there is a value to it, I don't want `parent: null`

I'm trying to get a cleaner solution and not two pushes dependant upon the value being set. I would prefer the one push to encapsulate the check if possible

```
array.push({
    id: id,
    name: name,
    parent ? parent: parent : null
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `&&` operator, [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and spread syntax like this

```
array.push({
    id,
    name,
    ...(parent && { parent })
})
```

If `parent` is null, the `&&` operator will return null and spreading null returns an empty object. If parent has a value, `{ parent }` object created will be spread inside the object.

**Note**: This will also skip the `parent` key for all [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) parent values like `0` and `""`. But, you are using ternary operator on `parent`. So, I'm assuming those values aren't valid.

Here's a snippet:

```js
function create(parent) {
  console.log({
    id: 1,
    ...(parent && { parent })
  })
}

[null, undefined, 5, "a string"].map(create)
```

Comment: Just a question on this. If parent is the result of a function, how do I set parent to that function result. If I follow the above syntax, I get parent is not defined.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you create a fiddle? Is `parent` variable created and available in that scope?

Comment: Not the best fiddle but along this gist: https://jsfiddle.net/jxwba82p/ Assume value of parent will change and sometimes func will return null

Comment: @Nouman you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the array returned by the function to 2 variables `const [parentId, parentName] = getParent(parent) ?? []` And add the keys conditionally https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/ymgqnhxv/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the function `Object.assign` as follow

```
array.push(Object.assign({
    id: id,
    name: name,
}, parent ? {parent} : {}))
```

*Be careful with the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use ellipsis notation.

```
array.push({
    id: id,
    name: name,
    ...(parent ? {parent: parent} : {})
});
```

Comment: Why not just `{parent}`? and I think you did mean `spread operator`.

Comment: And what is if parent is set to 0?

Comment: The intent in the original code seems to be to omit it. But I'm going to wager that in the intended use case, if the value exists it's always an object, not a type with any falsey value.

Comment: Or none of the valid values are falsey -- e.g. 0 might not be a valid parent ID.

Comment: With the code you are right. But OP says: `want to push a value (parent) ONLY if that value exists.` and if set to 0 it's for me setted.

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
    id: id,
    name: name
};

if (parent !== undefined)
    obj.parent = parent;

array.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
let obj = {
  id: "id",
  name: "name",
  parent: null
}


let obj1 = {
  id: "id",
  name: "name",
  parent: "parent"
}



const array = [

  ...obj.parent ? [obj] : [],
];

const array2 = [

  ...obj1.parent ? [obj1] : [],
];


console.log(array)
console.log(array2)
```